issue doing SVN copy URL1 to URL2
I am attempting to perform an 'svn copy URL1 URL2' command.  The exact syntax that I'm using is:
svn copy https://company_svn_server/sandbox/trunk \ https://company_svn_server/sandbox/branches/20240816_whatever --username svn_user
When I execute this statement, I get the following prompt, and I enter the password:
Authentication realm: <https://company_svn_server:443> Sandbox Subversion Repositories - LDAP
Password for 'svn_user': *****************
I then get the editor pop-up to enter the message attached to this copy operation.  After saving that message, I get another password prompt and enter the password a second time, but it seems to not like the password:
Authentication realm: <https://company_svn_server:443> Sandbox Subversion Repositories - LDAP
Password for 'svn_user': *****************
Authentication realm: <https://company_svn_server:443> Sandbox Subversion Repositories - LDAP
Username: 
In the interest of following this to its conclusion, I answered this last prompt by entering the username 'svn_user', was prompted again for the password, which I entered.  This lead to a second prompt for username.  Entering the svn_user and password for the fourth time, the exercise reaches its final conclusion with the message:
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
I believe that the two prompts are because both the source and destination are URLs, so each requires authentication.  That doesn't really make sense, since SVN doesn't support copying from one repository to another, so the one authentication should work, but I don't know why else it would prompt twice for the password.  The fact that it prompts me to enter the comment for the copy operation, it seems like the first authentication event was successful.
I have confirmed that the username/password combination is correct by executing a checkout:
svn checkout https://company_svn_server/sandbox/trunk --username svn_user

In this scenario, I receive a prompt for password, enter the same password as above, and the checkout functions with no issue.
Any thoughts?

This turned out to be a self-inflicted issue.  We use AD to provide LDAP authentication, and the user svn_user was in a group that has read-only permission for this repository.  That's why the 'svn checkout' worked just fine.
Changing the command to specify a user with read-write permission allowed the 'svn copy' to work with no problems.
